# rabbitmqctl.bat on Windows XP: unable to connect to node rabbit@MYPCNAME: nodedown

Tags: windows, erlang, rabbitmq

I have just installed RabbitMQ on my WindowsXP PC. I have fulfilled the Erlang OPC15 prereq as well.

My rabitmq seems to be working. I did a simple test using pika in python and it seems to work. The service is urnning.

The problem is that I cannot do anything with rabbitmqctl.bat. I always get the response:

```
Status of node rabbit@MYPCNAME ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@MYPCNAME: nodedown
diagnostics:
- nodes and their ports on MYPCNAME: [{rabbit,3097},{rabbitmqctl17251,1132}]
- current node: rabbitmqctl17251@mypcname
- current node home dir: C:\Documents and Settings\Myuser
- current node cookie hash: NOTSUREIFTHISISSENSITIVESOREMOVED==
```

In my rabbitmq log file I get:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Feb-2012::17:01:22 ===
** Connection attempt from disallowed node rabbitmqctl17251@mypcname **
```

From various forums I deduce this has something to do with cookies. What cookies are we talking about? What do I need to do to be able to manage my RabbitMQ instance using rabbitmqctl.bat? Please word your answer in a way that a non-erlang non-functional programmer would understand.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Had the same problem, this instruction straight out of the [manual installation guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html) solved my problem:

**Synchronise Erlang Cookies (when running a manually installed Windows Service)**

Erlang Security Cookies used by the service account and the user
running `rabbitmqctl.bat` must be synchronised for `rabbitmqctl.bat` to
function.

To ensure Erlang cookie files contain the same string, copy the `.erlang.cookie` file from the Windows directory (normally `C:\WINDOWS\.erlang.cookie`) to replace the user `.erlang.cookie.` The user cookie will be in the user's home directory (`%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`), e.g. `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\.erlang.cookie` or `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.erlang.cookie` (Windows Vista and later).

Answer (score 2):

Shortcut command for @Lining answer:

```
copy C:\Windows\.erlang.cookie %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.erlang.cookie
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a file called .erlang.cookie in your $HOME directory and put a simple passphrase in there.

Then restart rabbitmq and it might work. If it doesn't then rabbitmq is doing something to make sure you cannot put a system wide cookie in place.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after replacing ".erlang.cookie" file under c:\Windows in C:\Documents and Settings\username folder, because cookie should be same as per my understanding.